# Reproduce in eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am not able to reproduce this query in eloquent.

How could I have made a query without eloquent?

```
select * from points where operator = 2 and (month(date) = '1' and day(date) >= 25 or month(date) = '2' and day(date) <= 24)
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you need to make the query with or without Eloquent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use DB facade for this purpose..

```
$query = "select * from points where operator = :operator and (month(date) = :monthDate and day(date) >= :dayDate or month(date) = :monthDate2 and day(date) <= :dayDate2)"

$points = DB::select($query,[
   "operator" => 2,
   "monthDate" => 1,
   "dayDate" => 25,
   "monthDate2" => 2,
   "dayDate2" => 24
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have `Point` model for `points` table,  below eloquent query should work :

```
<?php

$points  = Point::where('operator', 2)->where(function($q){
    return $q->whereMonth('date', '=', 1)->whereDay('date', '>=', 25);
})->orWhere(function($q){
    return $q->whereMonth('date', '=', 2)->whereDay('date', '<=', 24);
})->get();
```

Comment: but he asking without eloquent

Comment: Yes but he can not reproduce this query in eloquent thats why he is asking for raw query. What if we can help him to do it with eloquent? Raw query should be the last option :)

Comment: I agree with that but I guess he doesn't have a model for points.. Why people avoiding to use model can't understand..